# Referencing System.Xml in WPF application 3.0

Tags: .net, xml, wpf, xaml

What is the purpose of referencing System.Xml in a WPF applications? When I don't reference it my application runs fine. The only difference I notice is that without the reference Microsoft Visual Studio complains everytime I use "x:Type" in my XAML with the following message: The type "x:Type" was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.

Comment: Have you not just answered your own question?

Comment: I don't think so. If you have the answer then earn the points.